# Can I safely plug a 15amp socket to 13amp socket, through multiple adapters?

Tags: electrical

I bought a smart plug, I wanted to use it as remote control for my AC. I asked the electrician to replace the 15amp with a 13 amp socket. so I can plug the smart plug and then plug the AC to the smart plug.
He explaind it won't work and explaind the difference between 13 and 15 amp plugs.

I found online a fuse adapter such shown.
so I am thinking to plug a fuse adapter on the 15 amp wall socket, then insert the smart plug on it, then on the smart plug put another fuse adapter, then put the AC 15 am plug on the fuse adapter.

is this safe?

See the image for illustration of what I intend to do.

[image: see]

Comment: Wait, you *bought* the smart plug??  Why on earth did you buy a UK one, rather than the correct one for the plug used in your country?  That's your problem, take it back and get the right one.   If you are in the UK and using a foreign plug to get an extra 2A, same remedy, but get that country's smart module.  They will all work the same.

Comment: couldn't find 15 amp smart plug...
Also I thought I can replace the 15 amp AC plug with 13 amp. clearly I don't know much about these things.

now, do you think having these adapter is safe?

Comment: I see where India, Paki and ZA are the largest countries to use the plug, that might explain the difficulty of finding a smart adapter.  What's the amp rating of the air conditioner?

Comment: The air conditioner socket is 15 amp

Comment: then you're out of luck. UK style plugs are only rated at 13A.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not do this.**

1. First of all even you would have to admit that the assemblage would be unwieldy at best.
2. Secondly having so many connections in series increases the overall resistance of the circuit and leads to a voltage drop and increase in temperature.
3. Kludges like what you propose often lead to unfortunate results.

Get a true sense of danger and respect for high powered live mains connections  and live to tell your grandchildren about how to live a safe life.

Comment: should I tell them after the experience or before it?   

Thanks for the advice.